# How to call a JS file from a JQuery Function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a function in jQuery and I want that where that function is triggered one of my JS file should be called on that particular event.

I have tried the following but its not working.

```
$.getscript
```

How does one load a JS file in jQuery?

The thing is i have one page that is calling webservices through ajax and i am using Grid to display. and i have edit button in the grid. when the user press the edit button i want one tab (out to four) to be selected.. so for that i need to call a Tab.js in order to go to particular tab. here is Tab code..Wait i am editing the code of my post

Tabs Code

```
(function($, undefined ) {
$.widget( "mobile.tabs", $.mobile.widget, {
options: {
    iconpos: 'top',
    grid: null,
    load: function(event, ui) { },
    beforeTabHide: function(event, ui) { },
    beforeTabShow: function(event, ui) { },
    afterTabShow:  function(event, ui) { }
},
_create: function(){
    var
        $this = this,
        $tabs = this.element,
        $navbtns = $tabs.find("a"),
        iconpos = $navbtns.filter('[data-icon]').length ? this.options.iconpos : undefined;
    var $content = $tabs.closest('div[data-role="page"]').find('div[data-role="content"]');

    $tabs
        .addClass('ui-navbar')
        .attr("role","navigation")
        .find("ul")
            .grid({grid: this.options.grid });

    if( !iconpos ){ 
        $tabs.addClass("ui-navbar-noicons");
    }

    $navbtns
        .buttonMarkup({
            corners: false,
            shadow:  false,
            iconpos: iconpos
        })
        .removeClass('ui-link');

    // Set up the direct children of the page as the tab content, hide them
    $content.children().addClass('ui-tabs-content');

    // Now show the one that's active
    if( $navbtns.filter('.ui-btn-active').length == 0 )
        $navbtns.first().addClass('ui-btn-active');
    $content.children('#' + $navbtns.eq($this.currentTab()).attr('href')).addClass('ui-tabs-content-active');

    $navbtns.bind('click', function(event) {
        navButtonClick.call(this, event);
        return false;
    })
    .bind('tap', function(event){
        navButtonClick.call(this, event);
        return false;
    });

    function navButtonClick(event) {
        $navbtns.removeClass( "ui-btn-active" );
        $( this ).addClass( "ui-btn-active" );
        $this.changeTab(event, {
            currentTab: $navbtns.eq($this.currentTab()),
            nextTab: $(this),
            currentContent: $this.currentContent(),
            nextContent: $content.children($(this).attr('href'))
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    this._trigger('load', null, {
        currentTab: $navbtns.eq($this.currentTab()),
        currentContent: $this.currentContent()
    });
},
currentTab: function() {
    var $tabs = this.element,
    $navbtns = $tabs.find("a");
    return this.element.find('.ui-btn-active').parent().prevAll().length;
},
currentContent: function() {
    return this.element.closest('div[data-role="page"]').find('div[data-role="content"]').children().filter('.ui-tabs-content-active');
},
changeTab: function(event, ui) {
    if( this._trigger('beforeTabHide', event, ui) )
        ui.currentContent.siblings().andSelf().removeClass('ui-tabs-content-active');
    if( this._trigger('beforeTabShow', event, ui) )
        ui.nextContent.addClass('ui-tabs-content-active');
    this._trigger('afterTabShow', event, $.extend({}, ui, { previousContent: ui.currentContent, currentContent: ui.nextContent, nextContent: null }));
}
});
})( jQuery );

$('[data-role=page]').live('pagecreate', function(e) {
$(this).find('[data-role="tabs"]').tabs();
});
```

Comment: Can you share with us a bit of JS and HTML?

Comment: The thing is i have one page that is calling webservices through ajax and i am using Grid to display. and i have edit button in the grid. when the user press the edit button i want one tab (out to four) to be selected.. so for that i need to call a Tab.js in order to go to particular tab. here is Tab code..Wait i am editing the code of my post..

Comment: Can you share the code you've written? we don't want to change the library code 'mobile.tabs', I am sure that it is not necessary.

Comment: The page contain 2000+ line of code. So i think Stackoverflow does not allow this. And the basic thing i want that through a JQuery function the particular tab should be get selected. I can do this by changing in this Tab.js by changing $navbtns.first().addClass('ui-btn-active');   to   $navbtns.eq(2).addClass('ui-btn-active'); then it will by default select third tab. How can i do this by a function.

Comment: Is there a way to switch between the tabs programatically? IS this statement true? is that what you are trying to achieve? If so, your library might not allow you to do that. https://github.com/groovetrain/jQuery.mobile-Tabs/issues/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Google analytics example, I would suggest you add before you close your `<body>` tag:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var url = 'http://example.com/script.js';
   document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + url + "' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
 </script>
```

I am assuming you would need something like this:

```
$('#editBtn').click(function() {
   var url = '/js/Tabs.js';
   document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + url + "' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
});
```

Comment: I tried the code and its working.It is calling JS file but it is not calling rest of the my page file so the pages goes blank..

Comment: It could be that you need to add return false; to the event that triggers the loading

Comment: We are happy to help, please provide more information about the problem, share the code you've written

Answer (score 1):

Variables are case-sensitive. Try:

```
$.getScript
```

Comment: Sorry actually my code was like that i mean it was `$.getScript` ...but not working...have you any other solution??

Answer (score 0):

If you want the javascript to be embedded inline so that 'this' refers to the object calling the event, then I have no clue.

But to just have an external JS file run, you programmatically append another "" to the document.